# ValueError: The `weights` argument should be either `None` (random initialization)

Tags: python, valueerror

This code is for asl recognition its giving a value error
ValueError: The `weights` argument should be either `None` (random initialization), `imagenet` (pre-training on ImageNet), or the path to the weights file to be loaded.

error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
runfile('/Users/jenimathew/Desktop/ASL/firstasl.py', wdir='/Users/jenimathew/Desktop/ASL')

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/Users/jenimathew/Desktop/ASL/firstasl.py", line 360, in 
pretrained_model_1 = VGG16(weights = weight_path1, include_top=False, input_shape=(imageSize, imageSize, 3))

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/vgg16.py", line 117, in VGG16
raise ValueError('The `weights` argument should be either '

ValueError: The `weights` argument should be either `None` (random initialization), `imagenet` (pre-training on ImageNet), or the path to the weights file to be loaded.

can anyone help me with the error

code:

```
    import keras
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Lambda, 
    MaxPool2D, BatchNormalization
    from keras.utils import np_utils
    from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    from keras import models, layers, optimizers
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
    from sklearn.utils import class_weight
    from keras.optimizers import SGD, RMSprop, Adam, Adagrad, Adadelta, RMSprop
    from keras.models import Sequential, model_from_json
    from keras.layers import Activation,Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, 
    MaxPool2D,MaxPooling2D,AveragePooling2D, BatchNormalization
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint
    from keras import backend as K
    from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
    from keras.models import Model
    from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
    import os
    from glob import glob
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import random
    import cv2
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
    import seaborn as sns
    import zlib
    import itertools
    import sklearn
    import itertools
    import scipy
    import skimage
    from skimage.transform import resize
    import csv
    from tqdm import tqdm
    from sklearn import model_selection
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, 
    learning_curve,KFold,cross_val_score,StratifiedKFold
    from sklearn.utils import class_weight
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
    from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
    from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
   

    from IPython import get_ipython
    get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')

    #LOAD DATA


    imageSize=50
    train_dir = r"asl_alphabet_train"
    test_dir =  r"asl_alphabet_test"
    from tqdm import tqdm
    def get_data(folder):
        """
        Load the data and labels from the given folder.
        """
        X = []
        y = []

        for folderName in os.listdir(folder+"/"+folder):

            print("Processing ", folderName)

            if not folderName.startswith('.'):
                if folderName in ['A']:
                    label = 0
                elif folderName in ['B']:
                    label = 1
                elif folderName in ['C']:
                    label = 2
                elif folderName in ['D']:
                    label = 3
                elif folderName in ['E']:
                    label = 4
                elif folderName in ['F']:
                    label = 5
                elif folderName in ['G']:
                    label = 6
                elif folderName in ['H']:
                    label = 7
                elif folderName in ['I']:
                    label = 8
                elif folderName in ['J']:
                    label = 9
                elif folderName in ['K']:
                    label = 10
                elif folderName in ['L']:
                    label = 11
                elif folderName in ['M']:
                    label = 12
                elif folderName in ['N']:
                    label = 13
                elif folderName in ['O']:
                    label = 14
                elif folderName in ['P']:
                    label = 15
                elif folderName in ['Q']:
                    label = 16
                elif folderName in ['R']:
                    label = 17
                elif folderName in ['S']:
                    label = 18
                elif folderName in ['T']:
                    label = 19
                elif folderName in ['U']:
                    label = 20
                elif folderName in ['V']:
                    label = 21
                elif folderName in ['W']:
                    label = 22
                elif  folderName in ['X']:
                    label = 23
                elif folderName in ['Y']:
                    label = 24
                elif folderName in ['Z']:
                    label = 25
                elif folderName in ['del']:
                    label = 26
                elif folderName in ['nothing']:
                    label = 27
                elif folderName in ['space']:
                    label = 28
                else:
                    label = 29


                for image_filename in tqdm(os.listdir(folder + "/" + folder+"/"+folderName)):

                    img_file = cv2.imread(folder + "/" + folder+"/"+folderName + "/" + 
    image_filename)
                    if img_file is not None:
                        img_file = skimage.transform.resize(img_file, (imageSize, imageSize, 3))
                        img_arr = np.asarray(img_file)
                        X.append(img_arr)
                        y.append(label)
       # print("X",X,"y",y)
        X = np.asarray(X)
        y = np.asarray(y)

        return X,y
    X_train, y_train = get_data(train_dir)
    #X_test, y_test= get_data(test_dir) # Too few images
   
    print(y_train)
   
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, 
    test_size=0.2,train_size=0.8)
    #print(X_train,y_train)
    # Encode labels to hot vectors (ex : 2 -> [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
    y_trainHot = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes = 30)
    y_testHot = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes = 30)

    # Shuffle data to permit further subsampling


    from sklearn.utils import shuffle
    X_train, y_trainHot = shuffle(X_train, y_trainHot, random_state=13)
    X_test, y_testHot = shuffle(X_test, y_testHot, random_state=13)
    X_train = X_train[:30000]
    X_test = X_test[:30000]
    y_trainHot = y_trainHot[:30000]
    y_testHot = y_testHot[:30000]

    #DATA VISUALIZATION

    def plotHistogram(a):
        """
        Plot histogram of RGB Pixel Intensities
        """
        plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
        plt.subplot(1,2,1)
        plt.imshow(a)
        plt.axis('off')
        histo = plt.subplot(1,2,2)
        histo.set_ylabel('Count')
        histo.set_xlabel('Pixel Intensity')
        n_bins = 30
        plt.hist(a[:,:,0].flatten(), bins= n_bins, lw = 0, color='r', alpha=0.5);
        plt.hist(a[:,:,1].flatten(), bins= n_bins, lw = 0, color='g', alpha=0.5);
        plt.hist(a[:,:,2].flatten(), bins= n_bins, lw = 0, color='b', alpha=0.5);
    plotHistogram(X_train[1])

    #3 images from category A

    multipleImages = glob('asl_alphabet_train/asl_alphabet_train/A/**')
    def plotThreeImages(images):
        r = random.sample(images, 3)
        plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
        plt.subplot(131)
        plt.imshow(cv2.imread(r[0]))
        plt.subplot(132)
        plt.imshow(cv2.imread(r[1]))
        plt.subplot(133)
        plt.imshow(cv2.imread(r[2]))
    #;
    #plotThreeImages(multipleImages)


    #3 images from category B

    multipleImages = glob('asl_alphabet_train/asl_alphabet_train/B/**')
    def plotThreeImages(images):
        r = random.sample(images, 3)
        plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
        plt.subplot(131)
        plt.imshow(cv2.imread(r[0]))
        plt.subplot(132)
        plt.imshow(cv2.imread(r[1]))
        plt.subplot(133)
        plt.imshow(cv2.imread(r[2]))
    #plotThreeImages(multipleImages)


    #20 images from category "A"
    print("A")
    multipleImages = glob('../input/asl-alphabet/asl_alphabet_train/asl_alphabet_train/A/**')
    i_ = 0
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10.0, 10.0)
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
    for l in multipleImages[:25]:
        im = cv2.imread(l)
        im = cv2.resize(im, (128, 128))
        plt.subplot(5, 5, i_+1) #.set_title(l)
        plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)); plt.axis('off')
        i_ += 1

    #20 images from category "B"

    print("B")
    multipleImages = glob('../input/asl-alphabet/asl_alphabet_train/asl_alphabet_train/B/**')
    i_ = 0
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10.0, 10.0)
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
    for l in multipleImages[:25]:
        im = cv2.imread(l)
        im = cv2.resize(im, (128, 128))
        plt.subplot(5, 5, i_+1) #.set_title(l)
        plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)); plt.axis('off')
        i_ += 1

    print('xtrainnnnnnnnnnnnnnn')
    #print(X_train)
    print('ytrainnnnnnnnnnnnnnn')
    print(y_train)
    map_characters = {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G', 7: 'H', 8: 'I', 9: 
    'J', 10: 'K', 11: 'L', 12: 'M', 13: 'N', 14: 'O', 15: 'P', 16: 'Q', 17: 'R', 18: 'S', 19: 
    'T', 20: 'U', 21: 'V', 22: 'W', 23: 'X', 24: 'Y', 25: 'Z', 26: 'del', 27: 'nothing', 28: 
    'space', 29: 'other'}
    dict_characters=map_characters
    import seaborn as sns
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df["labels"]=y_train
    print('lulllllllllll')
    print(df)
    lab = df['labels']
    print('lulllllllllll')
    print(lab)
    dist = lab.value_counts()
    sns.countplot(lab)
    print(dict_characters)


    # Helper Functions  Learning Curves and Confusion Matrix

    from keras.callbacks import Callback, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint

    class MetricsCheckpoint(Callback):
        """Callback that saves metrics after each epoch"""
        def __init__(self, savepath):
            super(MetricsCheckpoint, self).__init__()
            self.savepath = savepath
            self.history = {}
        def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
            for k, v in logs.items():
                self.history.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
            np.save(self.savepath, self.history)

    def plotKerasLearningCurve():
        plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
        metrics = np.load('logs.npy')[()]
        filt = ['acc'] # try to add 'loss' to see the loss learning curve
        for k in filter(lambda x : np.any([kk in x for kk in filt]), metrics.keys()):
            l = np.array(metrics[k])
            plt.plot(l, c= 'r' if 'val' not in k else 'b', label='val' if 'val' in k else 
    'train')
            x = np.argmin(l) if 'loss' in k else np.argmax(l)
            y = l[x]
            plt.scatter(x,y, lw=0, alpha=0.25, s=100, c='r' if 'val' not in k else 'b')
            plt.text(x, y, '{} = {:.4f}'.format(x,y), size='15', color= 'r' if 'val' not in k 
    else 'b')   
        plt.legend(loc=4)
        plt.axis([0, None, None, None]);
        plt.grid()
        plt.xlabel('Number of epochs')
        plt.ylabel('Accuracy')

     def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                               normalize=False,
                               title='Confusion matrix',
                               cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
        """
        This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
        Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
        """
        plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
        plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
        plt.title(title)
        plt.colorbar()
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
        plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=90)
        plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)
        if normalize:
            cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]

        thresh = cm.max() / 2.
        for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
            plt.text(j, i, cm[i, j],
                     horizontalalignment="center",
                     color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.ylabel('True label')
        plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

    def plot_learning_curve(history):
        plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
        plt.subplot(1,2,1)
        plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
        plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
        plt.title('model accuracy')
        plt.ylabel('accuracy')
        plt.xlabel('epoch')
        plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
        plt.savefig('./accuracy_curve.png')
        plt.subplot(1,2,2)
        plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
        plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
        plt.title('model loss')
        plt.ylabel('loss')
        plt.xlabel('epoch')
        plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
        plt.savefig('./loss_curve.png')
    
    
    map_characters1 = map_characters
    class_weight1 = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y_train), y_train)
    weight_path1 = '../input/keras-pretrained- 
    models/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'
    weight_path2 = '../input/keras-pretrained- 
    models/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'
    pretrained_model_1 = VGG16(weights = weight_path1, include_top=False, input_shape=.  
    (imageSize, imageSize, 3))
    #pretrained_model_2 = InceptionV3(weights = weight_path2, include_top=False, input_shape=. 
   (imageSize, imageSize, 3))
    optimizer1 = keras.optimizers.Adam()
    optimizer2 = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001)
    def pretrainedNetwork (xtrain, ytrain,xtest,ytest,pretrainedmodel, pretrainedweights, 
    classweight, numclasses, numepochs,optimizer,labels):

         base_model = pretrained_model_1 # Topless
        # Add top layer
        x = base_model.output
        x = Flatten()(x)
        predictions = Dense(numclasses, activation='softmax')(x)
        model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
        # Train top layer
        for layer in base_model.layers:
            layer.trainable = False
         model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                       optimizer=optimizer, 
                       metrics=['accuracy'])
         callbacks_list = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=3, 
    verbose=1)]
        model.summary()
        # Fit model
         history = model.fit(xtrain,ytrain, epochs=numepochs, class_weight=classweight, 
    validation_data=(xtest,ytest), verbose=1,callbacks = [MetricsCheckpoint('logs')])
         # Evaluate model
         score = model.evaluate(xtest,ytest, verbose=0)
         print('\nKeras CNN - accuracy:', score[1], '\n')
        y_pred = model.predict(xtest)
        print('\n', sklearn.metrics.classification_report(np.where(ytest > 0)[1], 
    np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), target_names=list(labels.values())), sep='') 
        Y_pred_classes = np.argmax(y_pred,axis = 1) 
        Y_true = np.argmax(ytest,axis = 1) 
        confusion_mtx = confusion_matrix(Y_true, Y_pred_classes) 
        plotKerasLearningCurve()
        plt.show()
        plot_learning_curve(history)
        plt.show()
        plot_confusion_matrix(confusion_mtx, classes = list(labels.values()))
        plt.show()
        return model
    pretrainedNetwork(X_train, y_trainHot, X_test, 
    y_testHot,pretrained_model_1,weight_path1,class_weight1,30,10,optimizer1,map_characters1)
```

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace for your error message, not just the text - it's hard to see where the error occurs and your code doesn't run by itself, so people cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KCuaUNa9

Comment: Don't provide information required in the question behind links or in the comments, but add the relevant information to the question itself.